# @-symbol doesn't work on GalliumOS (German keyboad)

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, german

Freshly installed Gallium OS on Acer Chromebook 14 (Edgar) won't let me type the @-symbol (I copied it from Wikipedia for this post)

It's supposed to be on ALT + Q on German keyboard settings, but nothing works. I tried Shift + ALT + Q and every other combination I could think of. It's not set elsewhere because I tried all other symbols out. Those are all where they are supposed to be.

I switched through every single flavor of German keyboard types and restarted the machine. No luck.

Any ideas? Cheers

edit: the ALT key itself works, but I just found out I can't use the pipe symbol either. It requires the ALT + > combination. So there seems to be a problem with that constellation

Comment: On a regular German keyboard, the *Alt* key is not used at all for typing characters. Only *Alt Gr* (the right *Alt* key) is. Are you using the right key?

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't consciously know that, but yes, I've always used the right one. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to switch the layout in keyboard settings to "Chromebook (most models) | search overlay"